# how to set string input default value when the input value is null in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I am set a string parameter in Jenkins pipeline(groovy script) like this:

```
def call(String type, Map map) {
    if (type == "gradle") {
        pipeline {
            agent any
            parameters {
                string(name: 'k8sResourceType', defaultValue: "${map.k8sResourceType}", description: 'Kubernetes Resource Type')
            }
    }
}
```

is it possible to set a default value when `${map.k8sResourceType}` is null? if the `${map.k8sResourceType}` is null set the Kubernetes resource type to `Deployment`. Because 90% of apps are `Deployment` and only special apps are `StatefulSet` in Kubernetes. I am a newbie in groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use `environment` instead of `parameters` to achieve what you want

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
            k8sResourceType = getResourceType(map.k8sResourceType)
    }
    stages {
        stage('Hello World') {
            steps {
                    echo "Value: ${env.k8sResourceType}"
            }
        }
    }
}

def getResourceType(value) {
    return value == null ? "Deployment" : value
}
```